# How to extract this?

Tags: php, regex

I have several PHP files, I want to manually parse the value of an array without using the PHP engine.

They look like this:

```
$LANG['help']['attribute_label'] = 'Label';
```

And others are only with one attribute, like this:

```
$LANG['adm_something'] = 'Label';
```

I need to extract 'Label' without the quotes from all lines. I have not yet found a Regex pattern that will match. I'm also open to other options.

Comment: so in the example of:   `$LANG['test'] = 'XYZ';` you want the regex to return 'XYZ'?

Comment: couldn't you simply include the files? the PHP engine will do the parsing for you...

Comment: No. I am using $file_handle to go through each line and need to extract XYZ all the way down. I check if the first character is $..

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/\\\$LANG['a-zA-Z\[\]_]*\s=\s\'([A-Za-z0-9]+)/", $line, $matches);
```

`$matches[1]` will contain the word Label in both provided cases

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all("/(\\\$[^=]*)[\s\t\r\n]*=[\s\t\r\n]*([^\r\n]*);/s", file_get_contents('-- PUT THE FILE NAME HERE--'), $matches);
$results = array();
foreach ($matches[1] as $key=>$var) {
    $results[trim($var)] = trim(trim($matches[2][$key], '\'"'));
}
var_dump($results);
```

That will find all of the variable declarations in the file, working with single or double quotes, as well as integer values (they don't necessarily need to be in quotes) or even arrays. Note that it'll only work where the entire value is on one line - and it's pretty stupid of a regex overall. But it should work for this case.

Comment: How can I catch those lines that do not match Regex?

Comment: Do you actually have any lines like that? Is there a particular reason you can't just include the file and reference the variables?

Comment: I wish to loop through this file to translate it.. But I would also like to keep any comments etc.

Comment: I don't understand why you need regex if that's your goal. You can recursively scan the array for entries/values.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/= \'(.+)\';/', '$LANG[\'help\'][\'attribute_label\'] = \'Label\';', $matches );

print_r( $matches );


Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => = 'Label';
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Label
    )
)
```